# Void pointer to object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, mbed

I'm developing a GUI for a mbed microcontroller in C++ and I have a few problems.

The situation is:
Different widget classes (button, slider...) with a widget virtual parent function. Then a virtual function layout with also classes like (gridLayout, ...). The layout has functions like layout.add(*widget) to add the widget pointers to a vector.
Then I have a controller function that handle the touch events and uses the current active layout to check what the correct widget is in the layout at the x,y coordinates of the touch.

Now I want to add a pointer pointed to a layout in the widget class so the controller class can possible change the activeLayout if this is required. There is also a function pointer so the controller can run a certain function when a widget is used.

Now the problem: I would like to do something like this:

```
Button::Button(char* text_, int color_, void *function_, Layout *layout_): text(text_), color(color_), function(function_), layout(layout_){}
```

But then I need to include the layout class, and the layout class already includes the widget class --> error! What is the easiest way to do this? I already tried void* pointers and then a static cast to Layout but that didn't work.

I also need to include a TFT class in every widget and layout, what would be the easiest way to do that? Now I just have a Display.h with in it:

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

static SPI_TFT Screen(LCD_SDI, LCD_SDO, LCD_SCK, LCD_CS,"Screen");

#endif
```

But I don't really think this is the correct way to do something like this.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So C **XOR** C++? The usage of `void *` differs **radically** in the two languages.

Comment: Sorry, it is C++ (added that it is C++ in the topic.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but i think you are looking for _forward declaration_ of a class (`class Layout;`)

Comment: Forward declaration is the solution.

Comment: Ok, so I just add class Layout; in the Widget.h and it will work?
Should I also do the same with the SPI_TFT Screen or should I use something like extern?

Comment: @Jannes: The `Screen` is a global object and those are declared with `extern` (and defined without anything). So `extern SPI_TFT Screen;` in header and `SPI_TFT Screen(LCD_SDI, ...)` in _one_ `.cpp`. With `static` you have _different_ object in each compilation unit (because `static` means you want the thing local to a compilation unit).

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Those were the things I had problems with (I have never done such a difficult piece of code, so I never used those things). The static thing makes sense, that is why my screen flashed multiple times at booting (initialized for each object)
EDIT: can I also just add the extern SPI_TFT Screen to the virtual classes?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: using forward declaration in each class. `class Layout;`

Then for the TFT class i had to use `extern SPI_TFT Screen;` and in my main.cpp I did the `SPI_TFT Screen(LCD_SDI, LCD_SDO, LCD_SCK, LCD_CS,"Screen");`

(thank you very much t.niese, Lightness Races in Orbit and Jan Hudec)